# React native - ScrollView doesn't work on mobile but it works on web

Tags: react-native, expo, scrollview

I got this react native page (I use expo). If you press on the yellow part, the cyan background list will show up.
[image]

[image]

But even if it's all wrapped in a ScrollView, when the content go over the page lower limit the page doesn't became scrollable. This only happen on android emulator, if I run it on web it works correctly.

CODE:
InventorySummaryPage.js

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { Dimensions, View } from "react-native";
import ImageButton from "../../../base/ImageButton/ImageButton";
import icons from "../../../../assets/icons/ImageAssets";
import InventoryItemDisplayRow from "./InventoryItemDisplayRow";
import { ScrollView } from "react-native";

export default class InventorySummaryPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            locationContent: {}
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if(this.props.showInventoryPage === "summary" &&
           this.props.showInventoryPage != prevProps.showInventoryPage) {
            this.filterContent()
        }
    }

    filterContent() {
        //check what filter is active and filter the content
        let itemsInLocation = this.props.inventorySummary.filter((elem) => (elem.location == this.props.locationSelected))
        let itemsGroups = {}
        itemsInLocation.forEach((item) => {
            if(itemsGroups[item.itemId]) {
                itemsGroups[item.itemId].totalWeight += item.itemWeight ? item.itemWeight * item.itemQuantity : 0,
                itemsGroups[item.itemId].totalQuantity += Number(item.itemQuantity),
                itemsGroups[item.itemId].content.push({
                    id: item.id,
                    quantity: item.itemQuantity,
                    weight: item.itemWeight,
                    comment: item.comment
                })
                //itemsGroups[item.itemId].comments = this.checkFilterComments()
            } else {
                itemsGroups[item.itemId] = {
                    name: item.itemName,
                    totalWeight: item.itemWeight ? item.itemWeight * item.itemQuantity : 0,
                    totalQuantity: Number(item.itemQuantity),
                    content: [{
                        id: item.id,
                        quantity: item.itemQuantity,
                        weight: item.itemWeight,
                        comment: item.comment
                    }]
                    //comments: this.checkFilterComments()

                }
            }
        });
        this.setState({locationContent: itemsGroups})
    }

    checkFilterComments() {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{
                display: this.props.showInventoryPage === "summary" ? "flex" : "none",
                width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
                flex: 1,
                height: "auto"
            }}>   
                <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{alignItems: "center"}}>
                    <ImageButton 
                        onClick={this.props.showAddItemPage}
                        style={{
                            width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.8,
                            padding: 0,
                            marginVertical: 5
                        }}
                        iconImage={icons.add_icon} 
                        label={"Add a new item"}
                    />
                    {
                    Object.keys(this.state.locationContent).map((key) => {
                        let item = this.state.locationContent[key]
                        return(
                        <InventoryItemDisplayRow
                            //style={{width: 100}}
                            key={key} 
                            content={item}
                        />
                        )
                    })
                    }
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

InventoryItemDisplayRow.js

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import InventoryItemDisplayRowInner from "./InventoryItemDisplayRowInner";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import ImageButton from "../../../base/ImageButton/ImageButton";
import { Pressable } from "react-native";
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";
import InventoryPageStyles from "../resources/InventoryPageStyles";
import { Shadow } from "react-native-shadow-2";

export default class InventoryItemDisplayRow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showInnerMenu: false
    };
  }

  openMenu = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      showInnerMenu: !prevState.showInnerMenu
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={this.props.style}>        
        <Pressable style={{zIndex: 2,}} onPress={this.openMenu}>
          <Shadow 
            distance={1} 
            startColor={'#0005'} 
            //endColor={'#0007'}
            offset={[1, 3]}
          >
            <View
            style={{
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "row",
                borderRadius: 20,
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderStyle: "solid",
                borderColor: "black",
                width: Dimensions.get("screen").width * 0.9, //(this.props.style?.width ? this.props.style.width : 0.9),
                paddingVertical: 5,
                paddingHorizontal: 15,
                height: Dimensions.get("screen").height * 0.06,
                alignItems: "center",
                position: "relative",
                backgroundColor: "yellow",
                marginBottom: 10,
                //shadow
                // elevation: 5,
                // shadowColor: '#000',
                // shadowOffset: {width: 3, height: 3},
                // shadowOpacity: 0.7,
                // shadowRadius: 1
            }}
            >
            <Text
                style={[{
                height: Dimensions.get("screen").width * 0.1,
                width: Dimensions.get("screen").width * 0.1,
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderStyle: "solid",
                borderColor: "black",
                borderRadius: 15
                }, InventoryPageStyles.inventoryItemCardQuantity]}
            >
                {this.props.content.totalQuantity}
            </Text>
            <View
                style={{
                marginVertical: 0,
                marginHorizontal: 15,
                width: Dimensions.get("screen").width * 0.4,
                textAlign: "left",
                verticalAlign: "top"
                }}
            >
                <Text style={InventoryPageStyles.inventoryItemCardMainName}>{this.props.content.name}</Text>
                <Text>{this.props.desc}</Text>
            </View>
            <Text style={InventoryPageStyles.inventoryItemCardWeight}>{this.props.content.totalWeight}</Text>
            </View>
        </Shadow>
        </Pressable>

        <View
          style={{
            display: this.state.showInnerMenu ? "block" : "none",
            marginLeft: Dimensions.get("screen").width * 0.1,
            width: Dimensions.get("screen").width * 0.8, //(this.props.style?.width ? this.props.style.width - 0.1 : 0.8),
            borderStyle: "solid",
            borderColor: "black",
            borderRadius: 15,
            borderTopRightRadius: 0,
            paddingVertical: 5,
            paddingHorizontal: 15,
            backgroundColor: "lightblue",
            bottom: 25,
            position: "relative",
            zIndex: 1,
            paddingTop: 30
          }}
        >
          {this.props.content.content.map((item) => (
            <InventoryItemDisplayRowInner 
              key={item.id}
              name={item.comment} 
              weight={item.weight}
              quantity={item.quantity}
            />
          ))}
          <ImageButton label={"SAVE"}/>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can get answer quickly if upload your code on https://snack.expo.dev/

Comment: I can't. Exporting on snack the real code would take so much time since there are a lot of custom component and I take all the data that i'm showing from a db. I tried to create a simpler version but for some reason it works. So i'm stucked all over again

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/wOXCUTps2 this is the simple example that unfrotunatel workd